# multi knapsack with limit on number of knapsacks an item can be placed in

Tags: or-tools

If i have a multiknapsack, but I want to limit the number of knapsacks each item can be placed it, it doesn't seem clear from the example.  So, for example, I have 10 knapsacks, and I have items that can be placed in two knapsacks at the same time.  I have code like this:

```
x[(item, bag)] = model.NewIntVar(0, 1, 'x_%s_%s' % (item, bag))
model.Add(
    len(set(bag
        for item in data['all_items']
        for bag in data['all_bags']
        if x[(item, bag)] > 0
    )
) <= 2)
```

how would I create a criteria like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a boolean that indicates whether an item is in a bag.

```
presence[(item, bag)] = model.NewBoolVar("")
model.Add(x[item, bag] > 0).OnlyEnforceIf(presence[item, bag])
model.Add(x[item, bag] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(presence[item, bag].Not())
```

Then you can just constraint this sum

```
for item in data["all_items"]:
    model.Add(sum(x[item, bag] for bag in data["all_bags"]) <= 2)
```

Here is an example: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/balance_group_sat.py#L102

EDIT: Just realized that your x[(item, bag)] are actually booleans. So you can ignore the first part

Comment: My concern was about being able to add additional features to the initial variable. So if I added a third grouping and wanted to constrain then individually. I’ll look at the example you provided but if you have insight into this I’d appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't quite understand what you mean, could you elaborate more?

Comment: i ended up using your advice about `presence` and was able to get it working.  I'm finding it's getting really slow for assignment when I get above a few thousands possible combinations though.  Any advice on scaling or-tools?

Comment: basically i have two loops setting `x[(item, bag)]` and it's taking longer than I would expect to get through it.  let's say i have 100,000 items and 100 bags.  I would imagine this would be simpler since it's just basic item assignment, and then I set an AddImplication on each.  Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: If you are talking about the model building, you can't do much, python is a bit slow in that regard see: https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1663, https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1020, maybe you can simplify a bit your model